# Getting date in UTC timezone when using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datetime

I'm using Spring Boot and Hibernate 5 along with MySQL in my project.

How can I get a DateTime from the database in UTC instead of my JVM's timezone?

Is there any configuration to add to the `application.properties` like `jadira.usertype.javaZone` for Jadira or some other trick?

Comment: do you know the timezone coming out of database?

Answer (score 9):

Since Hibernate 5.2, you can now use the [`hibernate.jdbc.time_zone`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-date-time-and-timestamps-in-utc-time-zone-with-jdbc-and-hibernate/) configuration property.

Basically, you can now force the UTC time zone for all `TIMESTAMP` and `TIME` columns using the following configuration property:

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>
```

Comment: how to do this with annotation?

Comment: You don't need to use annotations. This is a global setting.

Comment: I am using Hibernate as JPA Vendor Adapter when setting above property i am getting error as invalid peroperty
` <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
   p:packagesToScan="service.slicing.model"
            p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>
   </bean>
  </property>
 </bean>`

Comment: Thanks I have done the correct configuration and timezone is working now.
`<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:packagesToScan="service.slicing.model" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone">UTC</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>`

Answer (score 3):

To set UTC for all the date fields add following fields to MySQL connection string:

```
useTimezone=true
serverTimezone=UTC
useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

Example connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://hostname/databaseName?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

AND

Use jadira user type to set UTC for a particular field

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime",
    parameters = { @Parameter(name = "databaseZone", value = "UTC")})
private DateTime dateTime;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default timezone of your JVM to UTC when you start your app like

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
```

This will make sure the date is always in UTC when it moves around in your application, saved to db, retrieved from db etc.. and can be converted to any desired timezone when required.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the date from the database and convert it to UTC

```
Date localTime = getDateFromDB();
String format = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date gmtTime = new Date(sdf.format(localTime));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, i tried Arul Kumaran and Sanj solutions but it's not working well. So i've chosen to store dates as varchar and use a converter to get it as a ZonedDateTime